# Windows Azure Toolkit for Java plugin does not work on a Mac

Tags: windows, service, azure, cloud

I am trying to create a Windows Azure Cloud Service. Therefore I used Eclipse (Indigo) on my Mac.

First I need to install *(Eclipse > Help > Install New Software > http://dl.msopentech.com/eclipse)* the ***Windows Azure Toolkit for Java*** plugin based on [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690946.aspx), but this is not possible on my Mac. No problems on a Windows machine!

The following error is thrown on installing the plugin:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
com.microsoftopentechnologies.wacommon.feature.feature.group [1.8.0.201211010928] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same issue on Linux and this is due to an OS filter applied to the plugin restricting its use to Windows. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190279/unable-to-install-windows-azure-plugin-for-eclipse-with-java-by-microsoft-openhttp://) for the similar problem with a user running Eclipse on Linux. The Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse has dependencies on the .NET SDK and can debug a program with an emulator (like Visual Studio), thus it cannot be used in a Linux/Unix environment.

See this [full description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694271.aspx) of the plugin on the official website.

But as stated in the answer you are still able to develop programs on Linux or MacOS using the Windows Azure SDK for Java.