# Unable to install Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse with Java (by Microsoft Open Technologies)

Tags: azure, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the *Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse with Java (by Microsoft Open Technologies)* from this URL: **`http://dl.msopentech.com/eclipse`**. I use Ubuntu 12.10 and Eclipse "Java EE IDE for Web Developers", Version: Juno Service Release 2, Build id: 20130225-0426.

I followed the steps explained in this tutorial: **`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690946.aspx`**. But I got this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazure.tools.sdk.feature.feature.group [0.4.0.201302082023] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to install the plugin with the same name from this url: http://webdownload.persistent.co.in/windowsazureplugin4ej/. However, its version is 1.4, whereas apparently, the latest version is 1.8. I tried to update the plugin using the update button in the dialog "about Eclipse", but encountered this error: "Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  com.persistent.winazure.eclipseplugin.feature.feature.group [1.8.1.201302082023] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised by how far you guys had gone. I do not think Azure Eclipse plugin would work on Linux at all. It has dependency on Windows Azure .NET SDK and the Windows Azure emulator inside of it. Get a Windows machine, or dual boot your ubuntu, bro!

Although you may not be able to Install Windows Azure Eclipse Plugin, you should still be able to write your Java program consuming Windows Azure Services ( such as storage, queue, table, service bus, media services ) via Windows Azure SDK for Java.

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java

Since it is open source, you can even have your own fork of it :)